# script tag to parse JSON: does it work?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, eval

I am writing a script where I need to parse JSON in browsers that don't support JSON.parse(). I have strict size objectives (total size < 20 kb) so I cannot rely on an external library like jQuery.

The usual approach would be to use eval() but I am concerned that it is not safe, as I have no control on the JSON strings (provided by an external source).

I came up with the idea to use a script tag to create my object:

```
var json='{"name":"Me","age":"30"}';
var scr=document.createElement("script");
scr.innerHTML="var obj="+json;
document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

This seems to work, as demonstrated here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bz8f7/

Am I missing something here? Are there cases where my method won't work, or won't be safe?

Note: I am aware that this method creates a global variable, and I am fine with that for my use case.

Comment: why not just use eval? it is effectively equal to what you are trying to do. your method is exactly as safe as eval, which means: not safe

Comment: @JanusTroelsen for the reason explained in the question (risk of script injection)

Comment: Using a `script` tag would be no more safe than `eval`. In both cases you're executing the given code. Only difference is that your `script` version is executing it globally, but you can achieve that with the `Function` constructor. Still not safe, but prevents access to local variables.

Comment: @Christophe: that risk is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still evaluating JavaScript, just by using a more complex, less efficient method than `eval`. It has all the safety issues of eval.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON polyfill like [JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/). This is a proper parser, which means it does not use `eval`, even if there is no native JSON support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does work. No, it has exactly the same drawbacks as `eval` (maybe it's even slower because of the DOM, and it creates a global variable if you don't want to use a global function like in JSONP).

Use `JSON.parse`, and shim it if you care for legacy browsers. There are lightweight libraries that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Douglas Crockford's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) which comes in at less than 20K before minification. Pretty much all browser implementations of `JSON.parse()` started off from it, so you shouldn't have any compatibility problems.